# How to free the memory of WPF datagrid Row?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, datagrid, backgroundworker

I am using a background worker class to update the rows in a DataGrid. it is a infinite loop, the updating process is continuous. As I continue this,i will get System.OutofmemoryException . My requirement is after 100k rows, I would like remove the 0th row and add the latest row to DataGrid. I am able to Remove the Rows but I am unable to free the memory allocated by Datagrid Rows.

My requirement is the usage of RAM should be constant as we add rows after 100k row. (means suppose if 100k rows allocates a memory of 250000KB, it should be same as we goes on adds the new rows). how can I achieve this?
How can free the memory allocated by the WPF datagrid Row?

the sample code which I used:

```html
<Window x:Class="TestMemLeak.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid  Name="dg1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="242" Width="517" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=sno}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Sno"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding col1}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Coloumn1"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding col2}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Coloumn2"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding col3}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Coloumn3"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding col4}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Coloumn4"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding col5}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Coloumn5"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding col6}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Coloumn6"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding col7}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Coloumn7"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Load_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

 namespace TestMemLeak
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   public  class test
    {
        public int sno{get; set;}
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
        public string col4 { get; set; }
        public string col5 { get; set; }
        public string col6 { get; set; }
        public string col7 { get; set; }

    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;           // For Background Worker
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }


    private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dg1.Items.Clear();
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(1000000);
    }
    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int max = (int)e.Argument;
        for (int i = 1;i<max ;i++ )
        {
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        int i = e.ProgressPercentage;
    if (i > 10000)
        {
            dg1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(dg1.Items[0]);             

        }
        dg1.Items.Add(new test() {sno=i,col1="test",col2="test",col3="test",col4="test",col5="test",col6="test",col7="test" });
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Task Cancelled.....");
        }

            // Check to see if an error occurred in the background process.

        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error while performing background operation." + e.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            // Everything completed normally.
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Task Completed..." + e.Result);
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: You need to use virtual data to solve this, see this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc(v=vs.110).aspx